# What is this error: File does not exist error with roxygenise?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have been using `roxygen2::roxygenise` quite successfully with my package to build exported and imported functions. However, I recently ran into this error which I am unable to resolve:

```
> roxygen2::roxygenise()
First time using roxygen2. Upgrading automatically...
Error: File file does not exist
```

This is not the first time I have used `roxygen2` with this package. In addition, I am not quite sure what "File file does not exist" means. Has anyone else seen this and been able to resolve it?

Comment: restarting Rstudio fixed it, roxygenise is working again, but I still have no idea why this happened.

Comment: I have this error with RKWard as well as with pure R console (an a kubuntu 16.04), but restarting does not help.

Comment: I also am getting this error. Any solution?

Comment: Not have a `DESCRIPTION` file also throws this error.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to set the working directory of R to be the package folder

Comment: This worked for me. I had setwd() to a different directory and setting it back to the root package directory resolved it. I believe it is also the reason why restarting RStudio will work.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when using:

```
roxygen2::roxygenise("mypackage")
```

But, I didn't get the error when I instead used:

```
library(roxygen2)
roxygenise()
```

I know this is no explanation and I can't comment upon whether this works beyond my case.